# Colorbox not opening second time

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox the following way.

```
$.colorbox({
     href:"test.jsp?ids="+selectIds,
     onClosed: function() {
        //some function call
     }
});
```

Works fine for first time. But Second time i click it says:

> TypeError: $.colorbox is undefined

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/55yBv/  It works fine here. But doesnot work in my code. Its a table with checkboxes and a button to change the values in table

Comment: any idea ..please help

Comment: did u find a solution

Comment: No..I am not using ColorBox any more. But do you have any fiddle for your problem. May be we can solve yours.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like jquery is loaded with colorbox content and the `$` object is reinitialized. Check twice that `<script>` tag with jquery is not loaded in ajax content

UPD:
Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzrboz0r/